# ALSA lib PyAudio Errors with ReSpeaker v2.0 USB Mic Array and Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: python, pi-4, audio, alsa, usb-audio

I have been having problems using the pyaudio library to access raw audio data from the [ReSpeaker Mic Array v2.0](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_Mic_Array_v2.0/) microphones. The example script below is provided from the link above, and it's configured properly for my setup:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

RESPEAKER_RATE = 16000
RESPEAKER_CHANNELS = 6 # change base on firmwares, default_firmware.bin as 1 or i6_firmware.bin as 6
RESPEAKER_WIDTH = 2
# run getDeviceInfo.py to get index
RESPEAKER_INDEX = 2  # refer to input device id
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
            rate=RESPEAKER_RATE,
            format=p.get_format_from_width(RESPEAKER_WIDTH),
            channels=RESPEAKER_CHANNELS,
            input=True,
            input_device_index=RESPEAKER_INDEX,)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RESPEAKER_RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(RESPEAKER_CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(p.get_format_from_width(RESPEAKER_WIDTH)))
wf.setframerate(RESPEAKER_RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

The output of this script is quite lengthy, but it's [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O-9EDO8hyk5xSKt1U9Rpv2nUBQtSbzZb/view?usp=sharing)

I have been searching for a long time trying to figure out how to fix these errors, but pyaudio refuses to work with seamlessly with my ReSpeaker USB mic array and R-Pi4 setup.